# Recalculate SnapKit Constraint on orientation change

Tags: snapkit

I want to recalculate the height constraint when the phone orientation changes. I'm using the functions `uninstall()` and `install()` to make this happen. However, it's not working as desired. Am I using them incorrectly?

```
class ActionOverlayViewController: UIViewController {
    private var tableView = UITableView()
    private var heightConstraint: Constraint?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.snp_makeConstraints { make in
            self.heightConstraint = make.height.lessThanOrEqualTo(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height).priorityHigh().constraint
            make.height.equalTo(242).priorityLow()
        }
    }

    override func updateViewConstraints() {
        tableView.snp_updateConstraints { make in
            self.heightConstraint.uninstall()
            self.heightConstraint.install()
        }
        super.updateViewConstraints()
    }

    override func traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
        updateViewConstraints()
    }
}
```

Comment: Is more easy use remakeConstraints. You need detect device change orientation to apply your constraints.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have your `tableView` to have different heights in Landscape and Portrait orientation you could use 2 different approaches:

**1. Height should be 200 in Landscape and 400 in Portrait:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let tableView = UITableView()
    var heightConstraint: Constraint?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(tableView)

        tableView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.top.left.right.equalTo(0)
            self.heightConstraint = make.height.equalTo(0).constraint
        }
    }

    override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
        let height = UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape ? 200 : 400
        heightConstraint?.update(offset: height)
    }
}
```

Here you only have to call `update(offset:)` on the constraint. No need to go through `updateViewConstraints()`. This works well if you have static heights.

**2. Height should be half of the screen height in Portrait and full screen in Landscape:**

Here you have to update the whole constraints because you don't use static heights. Because of that you do not need to keep a reference to the constraint, but you have to go through `updateViewConstraint()`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let tableView = UITableView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(tableView)
    }

    override func updateViewConstraints() {
        super.updateViewConstraints()
        tableView.snp.remakeConstraints { (make) in
            make.top.left.right.equalTo(0)
            if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
                make.bottom.equalTo(0)
            } else {
                make.bottom.equalTo(view.snp.centerY)
            }
        }
    }

    override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
        view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    }
}
```